# I want to protect a way of illustrating grammar

Tags: method, education, teaching, learning

I have a system of illustrating grammatical concepts with graphical representations. It is interactive, and will be displayed on a web page. I don't know if it counts as a "program" or not, and I wonder if I am looking at a patent or a copyright. I don't want to be too descriptive here, obviously, but I wonder if someone can help me onto the correct path.

Comment: It is not just patent or copyright, it might be patent and copyright. Copyright is a given.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer, but I do have patents. Copyright is a given. Your specific implementation will be copyrighted as will the underlying code. Whether or not your product is patentable is more complex. It certainly might be, but it depends on stuff that is technical legally. Certainly where you might decide to patent it matters. Also, the normal requirements for patentability are required such as usefulness, novelty and non-obviousness. What I will say is that you would be very well served to consult with an actual patent attorney. We can't tell you whether your product is patentable as you can't publicly disclose it to us. If you do seek a patent attorney, try to fine one with experience in software patents.